# Google App Engine: Creating entity categories

Tags: python-2.7, categories, app-engine-ndb

I have this entity kind **Book(ndb.Model)**:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

Each Book entity should be 'categorized' in pre-defined categories according to its genre (example: 'Horror', 'Fantasy', 'Romance', etc...)

I hope to build a **Genre Links Menu** of the genres, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/genre/horror">Horror</a></li>
    <li><a href="/genre/fantasy">Fantasy</a></li>
    <li><a href="/genre/romance">Romance</a></li>
</ul>
```

After researching, I've found that this can be achieved in different ways. One method is to use the **choices** property parameter:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    genre = ndb.StringProperty(choices = ['Horror', 'Fantasy', 'Romance'])
```

However, this method doesn't seem too scalable nor adaptable; that is, if I want to include a new category, I would need to manually edit the `class Book(ndb.Model)` as well as the **Genre Links Menu**, and the forms for creating and editing *Book entities*. For example:

```
# new-book.html
<form method="post">

    <label>Book Title:<br><input type="text" name="title"></label>

    <label>Genres:<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="horror">Horror<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="fantasy">Fantasy<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="romance">Romance<br>
            # Adding New Genre */
            <input type="checkbox" name="genre" value="mystery">Mystery<br>
    </label>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

There must be a better way! Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to set the property as 'repeated'

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    genre = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

which will let you add and query arbitrary number of categories.

Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties?hl=de#repeated

Comment: @haopei handling what? What do you mean? It works transparently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, rdodev. A challenge of using this method here is: how would you build the 'Genre menu links', or query a list of all categories when building the checkboxes? For example, if `example.com/book/1` is `['Mystery','Horror']`, while `example.com/book/2` is `['Romance']`, then how would you query all three categories of both books to be used to build the link menu?

Comment: That's not quite true. When you issue an equality query with a repeated property, it will match all entities where any of the repeated properties match. If you want to query for Books where they have the genre 'Romance' AND 'Horror', you could do this with an AND query: genre == 'Romance' AND genre == 'Horror'. If you wanted all books that matched Romance OR Horror you could use genre.in(['Romance', 'Horror']). See this page about repeated property queries: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#repeated_properties.

Comment: @PatrickCostello Right. I confused which one was which. The project I used to work on we used repeated properties a lot, so was going by memory, but you are correct. I'm going to swap edit my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: `bks = Book.query(Book.genre == 'Romance').fetch()` will retrieve all books with 'Romance' as one of the tags. You can also query, I believe, `Book.query(Book.genre.in(['Romance', 'Mystery'])).fetch()`, which will retrieve all books that are tagged either 'Romance' or 'Mystery'.